# repeat loop in Sql?

Tags: sql

how can i repeat some SQL statement until condition

```
    repeat                    
    SQL statement             
    ......                    
    until condition
```

.

```
select count(*) as Total from  Table
                                  _____________
    repeat                                     |
        total = result                         | how replace repeat and 
        R1 as (select total*20/100 from Table) | Until condition with an 
        R2 as (select total*20/100 from Table) | SQL statement 
        R3 as (select total*60/100 from Table) | how can i loop this code
        result =R1+R2+R3                       |
    until result = total          _____________|
```

Comment: SQL does not have loops. Maybe you can show us what you want to do and what SQL query you want to repeat?

Comment: Some branches of SQL has loops. SQL does not have loops directly. But e.g. [TSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) does

Comment: thank you for your reply
what i want to do is 
select count(names) from student

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Are you sure you need a loop ?  Since SQL is set-based; using loops in sql are mostly a smell, and in most circumstances, there are better solutions

Comment: i added a code how i use a repeat loop

Comment: Could you add the DBMS type as above comments asked?

Comment: i edited the question
what i want is transfer this code to SQL 
but they told me there is no loop in SQL !!!!
so how can i loop the code above?

Comment: you should take a step back from the "perceived" solution using a loop. Add your table definition as a `create table` statement, some sample data as `insert into` statement and the output you expect from that. It sounds to me as if this could be achieved with window functions, but without more details this is hard to tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only iterative construct in plain standard SQL is a "Recursive CTE". Other than that, there isn't any other way.

Now, if you are talking about about procedures and functions such as PL/SQL, PLpg/SQL, or TSQL, then there are a lot of different solutions.

Comment: how i use it 
i added a code in my question above .

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about **MS-SQL Server** you can use [`WHILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
WHILE Boolean_expression   
     { sql_statement | statement_block | BREAK | CONTINUE }
```

An example from MSDN:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
WHILE (SELECT AVG(ListPrice) FROM Production.Product) < $300  
BEGIN  
   UPDATE Production.Product  
      SET ListPrice = ListPrice * 2  
   SELECT MAX(ListPrice) FROM Production.Product  
   IF (SELECT MAX(ListPrice) FROM Production.Product) > $500  
      BREAK  
   ELSE  
      CONTINUE  
END  
PRINT 'Too much for the market to bear';
```